# Setting AutoLayout leading constraint to properly place label in custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios-autolayout

The default UITableViewCell layouts follow the convention, that the leftmost labels start exactly where the cell separator lines start (at `separatorInset`). I have to create a custom `UITableViewCell` which will be displayed along cells with default layouts, so I want my labels to start exactly where the defaults do.

How should I set a leading constraint of my label to place them right?

Here is my test:

1. cell (green): 16 px from left edge, no margin
2. cell (red): 20 px from left edge, no margin
3. cell (blue): 12 px from left margin
4. cell (white): "Basic" default cell layout

#### Small screens (3.5", 4", 4.7")

[image: Small screens]

#### Big screens (5.5", iPad)

[image: Big screens]

As you can see, on small screen factors the separatorInset is 16 px, on big screens it's 20 px. Margin does not work as expected: it is 8 px no matter how big the screen is.

Comment: you can set this margin dynamic from code depending on the device you are using, also you could create a custom UITableViewCell which keeps the same layout on all the devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the correct solution for this: you have to use size-class based constraint values like this:

[image: Label left constraint]

You have to set the default constraint value to 16, press the small plus button next to the constant field, add Regular Width > Any Height and enter 20 into the new field.